# How do I pass a "list of lists" as the argument to a function of the form F[x,y]?

Tags: list-manipulation, functions, arguments

I have a function `F[x,y]` and a list of the form:

```
{{a1,b1},{a2,b2},{a3,b3},{an,bn}}
```

Basically, I want to pass the list mentioned above as the argument to the function `F` and get the output as a list of the form:

```
{F[a1,b1],F[a2,b2],F[a3,b3],F[an,bn]}
```

How do I do this?

Answer (score 5):

[`Apply`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Apply.html) at [`Level`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Level.html) 1:

```
F @@@ list
```

> {F[a1, b1], F[a2, b2], F[a3, b3], F[an, bn]}

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
Map[Apply[F, Sequence[#]] &, {{a1, b1}, {a2, b2}, {a3, b3}}]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
MapThread[F,Transpose@lst]
```

> {F[a1, b1], F[a2, b2], F[a3, b3], F[an, bn]}

Answer (score 0):

You can always define you `F` with the appropriate pattern

```
f[{x_, y_}] := f[x, y]

f /@ {{a1, b1}, {a2, b2}, {a3, b3}, {an, bn}}
(* {f[a1, b1], f[a2, b2], f[a3, b3], f[an, bn]} *)
```

a variant to the other answers would be

```
Apply[f] /@ {{a1, b1}, {a2, b2}, {a3, b3}, {an, bn}}
(* {f[a1, b1], f[a2, b2], f[a3, b3], f[an, bn]} *)
```