# How to separately pass elements of a 3D list as part of the arguments of a function?

Tags: list-manipulation, function-construction, map, mapthread

I have a function whose arguments have the form F[a,b,c,d,e], but the 2nd to 4th arguments are in a list of the form  R={{{b,c,d},{e,f,g}},{{h,i,j},{k,l,m}}} how can I pass these elements as those the arguments of the function.

[Here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/203813/how-do-i-pass-a-list-of-lists-as-the-argument-to-a-function-of-the-form-fx-y) I have found a similar question, but in that case, all the arguments are in a list.

Comment: `R` has 2 items per sublist and there are 2 items. I was just wondering if these were four lists of 3 elements each?

Comment: R is a list that contains two list that each of them has 2 list of 3 elements. Sorry...I edited the title. @Syed

Comment: Oh i see. I thought you wanted to pass a 2D matrix into the function and that didn't make sense either. You can use `F[p,q,r,s,t]` to make the post more clear as the other symbols have been used in `R`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
R = {{{b, c, d}, {e, f, g}}, {{h, i, j}, {k, l, m}}};

Apply[F[a, ##] &, R, {2}]
```

> ```
> {{F[a, b, c, d], F[a, e, f, g]}, {F[a, h, i, j], F[a, k, l, m]}}
> ```

Also

```
Map[F[a, ##] & @@@ # &] @ R
```

> ```
> {{F[a, b, c, d], F[a, e, f, g]}, {F[a, h, i, j], F[a, k, l, m]}}
> ```

and

```
R /. {x_, y_, z_} :> F[a, x, y, z]
```

> ```
> {{F[a, b, c, d], F[a, e, f, g]}, {F[a, h, i, j], F[a, k, l, m]}}
> ```

Answer (score 2):

```
R = {{{b, c, d}, {e, f, g}}, {{h, i, j}, {k, l, m}}};
```

---

Using `Replace` at level `2`:

```
Replace[R, v_ :> F[a, Sequence @@ v], {2}]

(*{{F[a, b, c, d], F[a, e, f, g]}, {F[a, h, i, j], F[a, k, l, m]}}*)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
R = {{{b, c, d}, {e, f, g}}, {{h, i, j}, {k, l, m}}};
```

Using `MapApply` (new in 13.1)

```
MapApply[F] /@ Map[Prepend[a], R, {2}]
```

{{F[a, b, c, d], F[a, e, f, g]}, {F[a, h, i, j], F[a, k, l, m]}}

A variant of kglr's `ReplaceAll`

```
R /. {x__?AtomQ} :> F[a, x]
```

{{F[a, b, c, d], F[a, e, f, g]}, {F[a, h, i, j], F[a, k, l, m]}}

Answer (score 1):

```
R = {{{b, c, d}, {e, f, g}}, {{h, i, j}, {k, l, m}}};

R /. v_?VectorQ :> F[a, Sequence @@ v]
```

> {{F[a, b, c, d], F[a, e, f, g]}, {F[a, h, i, j], F[a, k, l, m]}}